# Reading a progressively encoded 9000x9000 JPEG in Java takes 1 minute

Tags: java, jpeg, javax.imageio

When using `javax.imageio.ImageIO` to load a large-resolution (9000x9000) JPEG from disk, it takes more than 1 minute in my scala application. I tried creating a Java-only project, but it still takes too long - around 30 seconds.

This is how I load the image:

```
File file = new File("/Users/the21st/slow2.jpg");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

Is there any way to improve performance on reading progressively encoded large-res JPEGs in Java?

The image in question is [this one](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/6l8de0cr4q1utah/slow2.jpg) (moderators, please don't reupload to other hosting site again so that encoding / quality doesn't change)

Comment: Loading that image (from a local file) using `ImageIO` in a simple java program takes about 1-2 seconds on my PC - where are you getting the image from? when you do it?

Comment: @Bret I didn't realize StackOverflow probably resized and/or re-encoded that image during upload to their server. This is the original image: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73774/slow2.jpg (edited original question with this link)

Comment: Have you tried using `InputStreamReader` and/or `BufferedReader`?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl Can you give an example? `ImageIO.read` does not take a Reader as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that progressive encoding is the culprit. If i re-encode your sample as baseline, the reading time goes down from ~40s -> ~2s.

Comment: Progessive coding should not slow down the decompression UNLESS the decoder is performing incremental updates of the images. There must be some setting in the encoder to tell it not to update the image under the final scan.

Comment: Perhaps you're GC churning, try increase heap memory

Comment: I have voted to reopen. "Are there any faster alternatives to ImageIO that can load JPEG images?" is not necessarily a recommendation for a tool. I had a number of programming suggestions.

Comment: a: What does your code look like? The way you read it, may make an impact. b: What is the source of your image? Whether you read from disk, network or memory may have a huge impact. c: Have you tried disable disk caching? `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)` (which is `true` by default) usually gives a speed increase (at the cost of using more memory).

Comment: Due to using a different code path, my [JPEG plugin for ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg) does read the image about twice as fast (on my computer JRE: ~18 sec, TM: ~8 sec, ymmv). This means that if you obtain the JRE  `ImageReader` for JPEG and use the `readRaster` method, you'll see the same speed up. Seems to be due to the progressive encoding, as noted by @barti_ddu PS: Voted for re-open, but can't answer yet...

Comment: This only takes a second to load on my 'puter. I have a few theories and work arounds you might be able to try but I am space limited until there are enough votes to reopen.

Comment: @user3344003 Can you read the original progressive JPEG from the dropbox link in the comments (not the imgur one from the question, that has been re-encoded as baseline) in 1 sec? If so, what kind of computer do you have, and how do you do it? I'm very interested!

Comment: I have Mac. It takes a second to load on the plain vanilla Preview app. I suspect that it is sampling the image for display.

Comment: How much RAM did you allocate to your app? By my estimates your preview image takes up roughly 950mb ram when loaded in memory. If you havent allocated enough RAM you might loose some overhead to the expansion of allocated ram. And if your RAM is nearly full it might start swapping to disk.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets I allocated 3 gigs to my app, `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` returns 2667 MBs. The images now takes 27s to load (not a significant improvement)

Comment: @haraldK I tried `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)` but that actually caused a 1-2s slowdown.

Comment: Have you tried `BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new BufferedInputStream(new
FileInputStream(file)));` ? I have noticed using a stream sometimes gives a speed increase. I dont know if the `read` utilises a stream internally. But I usually go with a buffered stream.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets Tried that, no improvement.

Comment: If you load this image in an application like the GIMP or photoshop on your computer. how long does this application take to load it if you do file open? On my i5 it takes about 5 seconds to load it from disc with a graphics application.  By testing this we can get a benchmark what speed it should achieve on your computer.

Comment: @the21st Then you are likely to be very low on memory (or your RAM is slower than your disk, but that's unlikely). It's not always faster, but I've never experienced it to be slower. You should probably do some profiling, to figure out where the bottlenecks are. And say something about your system, use case and show more code.

Comment: @user3344003 Oh, I thought you achieved that speed in Java... I think it should be doable to get close though, it's just a matter of how much time and energy you can spend.

Comment: @the21st Using my [`BufferedImageFactory`](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/common/common-image/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/BufferedImageFactory.java) class and the AWT `Toolkit`, like this `BufferedImage image =  new BufferedImageFactory(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(file.getAbsolutePath())).getBufferedImage();` I could read the image in ~2.5 sec (in Java).

Comment: Yeah, it's a real bummer. With the old com.sun.image.codec.jpeg.JPEGCodec that was removed in Java 7, it takes about 2 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here's my findings so far (and to be honest, they are a little worrying...).

Using the standard JPEG plugin for ImageIO bundled with the Oracle JRE:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

Reads the image in roughly **18 seconds** on my computer (a MacBookPro/2.8GHz i7).

Using my [JPEG plugin for ImageIO](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#jpeg), which uses a slightly different code path (i.e., you can probably get the same results by obtaining the `ImageReader` and invoking the `readRaster()` method, then creating a `BufferedImage` from that. The code is non-trivial, so please refer tho the project page if you like to see the code):

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

Reads the image in roughly **8 seconds** on my computer.

Using my [`BufferedImageFactory`](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/blob/master/common/common-image/src/main/java/com/twelvemonkeys/image/BufferedImageFactory.java) class and the AWT `Toolkit`:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImageFactory(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(file.getAbsolutePat‌​h())).getBufferedImage();
```

Reads the image in **~2.5 seconds** on my computer.

Using the deprecated `JPEGImageDecoder` class from `sun.awt.codec`:

```
BufferedImage image = new JPEGImageDecoderImpl(new FileInputStream(file)).decodeAsBufferedImage();
```

Reads the image in **~1.7 seconds** on my computer.

So, this means that we should be able to read this image in less than 2 seconds, even in Java. The performance from the `JPEGImageReader` is just ridiculous in this case, and I really like to know why. As already mentioned, it seems to have to with the progressive decoding, but still, it should be better than this.

*Update:*

Just for the fun of it, I created a quick PoC `ImageReader` plugin backed by the [LibJPEG-Turbo Java API](http://www.libjpeg-turbo.org/Documentation/Documentation). It's not very sophisticated yet, but it allows for code like:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

To read the image in **< 1.5 seconds** on my computer.

PS: [I used to maintain ImageIO wrappers for JMagick](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys/releases/tag/twelvemonkeys-3.0.2) (similar to the code mentioned by @Jordan Doyle, but it would allow you to program against the ImageIO API), however I stopped as it was too much work. Maybe I have to reconsider... At least it's worth checking out his solution as well, if you don't mind on relying on JNI/native code installation.

Comment: Is there a way to modify your `BufferedImageFactory` approach so that it can decode CMYK jpegs, too?

Comment: @the21st Sorry, it seems the `Toolkit.createImage` method doesn't support CMYK, so it won't work (and there's really not much we can do to fix it either). Both my original plugin and the LibJPEG-Turbo version does, though. ;-)

Comment: Quite a late comment for this thread. I have quite a slow PC and use Windows 10 / JDK14, and tried loading the image: ImageIO.read(file) takes 50 seconds, but JavaFX new javafx.scene.image.Image() takes just ~3.5sec.

Comment: @DuncG Interesting. The ImageIO plugin really should have some shortcut to avoid the progressive updates at least. But still, the difference you see is huge.

Answer (score 2):

One faster alternative to `ImageIO` is `ImageMagick`, there are various wrappers for interfacing `ImageMagick` via Java such as [JMagick](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick/)

To get a `BufferedImage` from JMagick you must first get an instance of `MagickImage` which can be done like so:

```
ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(pathToImage);
MagickImage image = new MagickImage(info);
```

Now you can use the method provided by our very own [Jacob Nordfalk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/456046/jacob-nordfalk) 8 years ago to read the image into a BufferedImage [here](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.jmagick/1147)

```
public static BufferedImage magickImageToBufferedImage(MagickImage magickImage) throws Exception
{
    Dimension  dim = magickImage.getDimension();
    int size = dim.width * dim.height;
    byte[] pixels = new byte[size * 3];

    magickImage.dispatchImage(0, 0, dim.width, dim.height, "RGB", pixels);

    BufferedImage bimage = createInterleavedRGBImage(dim.width, dim.height, pixels);

    ColorModel cm = bimage.getColorModel();
    Raster raster = bimage.getData();
    WritableRaster writableRaster = null;

    writableRaster = (raster instanceof WritableRaster) ? (WritableRaster) raster : raster.createCompatibleWritableRaster();

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(cm, writableRaster, false, null);

    return bufferedImage;
}
```

Then the `createInterleavedRGBImage` method:

```
public static BufferedImage createInterleavedRGBImage(int imageWidth, int imageHeight, byte data[])
{
    int[] numBits = new int[3];
    int[] bandoffsets = new int[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        numBits[i] = 8;
        bandoffsets[i] = i;
    }

    ComponentColorModel ccm = new ComponentColorModel(
        ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB),
        numBits,
        false,
        false, //Alpha pre-multiplied
        Transparency.OPAQUE,
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE
    );

    PixelInterleavedSampleModel csm = new PixelInterleavedSampleModel(
        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE,
        imageWidth,
        imageHeight,
        3, //Pixel stride
        imageWidth * 3, // Scanline stride
        bandoffsets
    );

    DataBuffer dataBuf = new DataBufferByte(data, imageWidth * imageHeight * 3);
    WritableRaster wr = Raster.createWritableRaster(csm, dataBuf, new Point(0, 0));
    return new BufferedImage(ccm, wr, false, null);
}
```